# How to set focus to grid after delete in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

jqGrid toolbar and inline delete buttons are used to delete rows.

On delete command delete dialog appears. After delete is confirmed or cancelled, grid will not get focus. Mouse click in grid is required to make keyboard navigation to work in grid.

How to set focus to grid after delete or if delete was cancelled so that additional mouse click is not required ?

delete button in toolbar:

```
        $.extend($.jgrid.del, {
            top: window.innerHeight/2-100,  
            left: window.innerWidth/2-120,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            errorTextFormat: function (response) { 
              clearModeless();
              return decodeErrorMessage(response.responseText, '', '');
              },
            reloadAfterSubmit: false,
            afterShowForm: function($form) {
                var form = $form.parent()[0];

                $("#dData",form).attr("tabindex","1000");
                $("#eData",form).attr("tabindex","1001");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#dData",form).focus(); 
                },50);
            }
           });


           $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#grid_toppager", { 

            search:  true,
            del: true,
            add: true,
            view: true,
            edit: true
          }, 

          {       url: '/erp/Grid/Edit?_entity=Klient'},

       {        url: '/erp/Grid/Add?_entity=Klient' },

        { url: '/erp/Grid/Delete?_entity=Klient',

          beforeShowForm: function(form) {
            var selected = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
            $("td.delmsg",form).html( 'Rows '+selected.length +'<br/>' +
                 'Delete?' );
            }
        }
);
```

Delete button in column:'

```
             colModel: [{"name":"_actions","formatter":"actions","viewable":false,"formatoptions":{"editbutton":true,"keys":true,"onSuccess":function (jqXHR) { jqXHRFromOnSuccess=jqXHR;return true;}
,"afterSave":function (rowId) {
  var data = $.parseJSON(jqXHRFromOnSuccess.responseText);
$grid.jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, { Kood: data.PrimaryKeyValues[0] }); 
cancelEditing($grid);afterGridSaveFunc(rowId,jqXHRFromOnSuccess);jqXHRFromOnSuccess=null; 
updateButtonState($grid);
}
,"restoreAfterError":false,"onError":errorfunc
,"extraparam":{"_dokdata":FormData
},"afterRestore":function () {
          updateButtonState($grid);
        }
,"onEdit":onInlineEdit
,"delbutton":true,"delOptions":{"url":"Delete","afterComplete":function (response, postdata, formid) { summarefresh($grid); }
}}},
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to my that you should set focus to the grid or to some another element inside of `afterComplete`. You use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` so I see no problem to set focus here. Currently you call `summarefresh` function. You can set focus directly after the call of `summarefresh`.

Comment: I added `afterComplete: function()  { alert('afterComplete');$grid[0].focus();}` to delete options. If Esc key or cancel button is pressed to delete question, message box does not appear and keys do not work. How to set focus back to grid after delete has cancelled?

Comment: Also if server returns error from delete controller and cancel is pressed, keys will not work. Also `$grid[0].focus()` sets focus to grid only. `multiselect:true` is used.  How to set focus to nearest deleted row or first row so that up/down arrow keys will move to text/previous row after delete?